# Troubles introducing SIMD commands into the code

Tags: simd

I have a basic calculation function that I apply on each item in an array. This function does more then just summing two vectors.

I wanted to work on multiple items from my array in parallel using SIMD commands.

As I found these kind of examples too simple for my case (they don't include function calls):
http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~nloriant/files/scfpsc-pc.pdf

I tried using array notation as in here:
http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/cpp/mac/optaps/common/optaps_elem_functions.htm

But this did not accelerate my code. I don't understand what I am doing wrong and if I need to go to the more assembly-like style of SIMD, how do I introduce function calls there...

If anyone can help me or refer me to a good source for my needs I'll be very thakful.

Thank you!!!!

---

code example:

This is the basic function applied on each item in the array:

```
float VarFlow::gauss_seidel_step(IplImage* u, int i, float h, float J11, float J12, float J13, float vi){

int x = i%u->width;
int y = i/u->width;

int start_y, end_y, start_x, end_x;
int N_num = 0;

start_y = y - 1;
end_y = y + 1;
start_x = x - 1;
end_x = x+1;         

float temp_u = 0;

// Sum top neighbor    
if(start_y > -1){              

    temp_u += *((float*)(u->imageData + start_y*u->widthStep) + x);

    N_num++;

}

// Sum bottom neighbor            
if(end_y < u->height){   

    temp_u += *((float*)(u->imageData + end_y*u->widthStep) + x);

    N_num++;

}

// Sum left neighbor
if(start_x > -1){              

    temp_u += *((float*)(u->imageData + y*u->widthStep) + start_x);

    N_num++;

}

// Sum right neighbor
if(end_x < u->width){              

    temp_u += *((float*)(u->imageData + y*u->widthStep) + end_x);

    N_num++;

}

temp_u = temp_u - (h*h/alpha)*(J12*vi + J13);
temp_u = temp_u / (N_num + (h*h/alpha)*J11);

return temp_u;
```

}

I'd like to declare it with __declspec (vector) and call it like so:

```
    u_ptr[0:max_i:1] = gauss_seidel_step(imgU, vect[0:max_i:1], h, fxfx_ptr[0:max_i:1], fxfy_ptr[0:max_i:1], fxft_ptr[0:max_i:1], v_ptr[0:max_i:1]);
    v_ptr[0:max_i:1] = gauss_seidel_step(imgV, vect[0:max_i:1], h, fyfy_ptr[0:max_i:1], fxfy_ptr[0:max_i:1], fyft_ptr[0:max_i:1], u_ptr[0:max_i:1]);
```

Instead of a for loop.

I'll be happy to get a direction with this (maybe a link to a similar example) but **not** a full solution.

Thanks!

Comment: A sample of the code might help here. Although my experience with SIMD is from 20 years ago, I do remember that writing *effective* code is quite challenging. In particular, although branching (`if` statements) is permitted, it can undermine any parallelism you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to write explicit SIMD code (e.g. using intrinsics) or use the parallel extensions of the Intel tools - the solution will be very different in each case. Perhaps you could post a simple example of code that you want to vectorize ?

Comment: I'm not sure SIMD allows for calling functions in parallel, but only for mathematical operations.

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up between SIMD and higher level parallel programming. SIMD is parallelism at the instruction level, but it looks like you want to use the Intel parallel programming tools which operate at a somewhat higher level of abstraction. You should probably drop the SIMD tag etc unless you specifically want to use e.g. SSE.

Comment: I tried using cilk_for but the overhead of creating a new thread is just not worth it. I was hoping I could achieve some paralleization at a lower level. Do you think it is hopeless? If so, is it because the function is too complex for that? Thank you, Paul (I really appreciate all your help and advice!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIMD and conditional branching do not mix well.

Turn your conditional statements into boolean masks and multiplications.  That will send you down the right path for vectorizing the operations.

e.g.

```
if(end_x < u->width){                  
    temp_u += value;    
    N_num++;    
}
```

becomes

```
ltmask = (end_x < u->width); // see _mm_cmplt_ps
temp_u += ltmask*value; // see _mm_add_ps, _mm_and_ps
N_num += ltmask; // use _mm_and_ps with a vector of 1.0f
```